# Why doesn't Interface Builder objects shows up on screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I've never had any problem with Interface Builder elements before (labels, sliders, switches etc), but suddenly I can't get new ones to show up in the app! 
I can drag them in to the view, arrange them as I want, set values etc, but when I run the code they are gone.
A mysterious thing is that I can set values to them in the code without problem, like:

```
self.myNewLabel.text = @"test"
```

And if I stop the code with a breakpoint and ask the console
**po self.myNewLabel.text** it gives me "test"
But still, nothing shows up on the screen!
I've searched for any *hidden* or *alpha* properties that was set by misstake, but found nothing.

What are the pitfalls here? What am I missing?

System Info:

- Xcode 6.1
- OSX 10.10
- Running on iOS 8.0 device

Comment: please post a screenshot of your storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the constraints created by Interface Builder - they may be inadvertently pushing your UI elements off-screen.

Comment: What a stupid misstake, I feel like an idiot. Yes, the constraints were set wrong! Thank you so much!